# f2.show() method does not show the progress bar in form2

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, progress-bar, modal-dialog

I have an application that has 2 forms. First one is where I do all the job and second one is just for displaying a progressbar.

I want to open the second one from the main form. if I use

```
Form2 newForm = new Form2();
newForm.Show();
```

`Form2` opens and closes when it needs to open and close, but I cannot see the progress bar. I just can see a blank instead of it.

When I use

```
Form2 newForm = new Form2();
newForm.ShowDialog();
```

I can see the progressbar but `Form2` doesn't close when it needs. It runs forever, what should I do?

I use a static public variable closeForm to close the second form.  When I need to close the form I set

```
closeForm = true;
```

and in the second form, I have a timer

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Form1.closeForm)
    {
        this.Dispose();
        this.Close();
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        progVal++;
        progressBar1.Value = (progVal % 100);
    }            
}
```

this is where I put the ProgressBar value and close the form.

When I use show method, I only see blanks instead of the controls in form2. not just the progressbar, and I want `form1` to close `form2`

Comment: you need to provide more code

Comment: How have you told your form2 to close when done?

Comment: i edited my question about how i close form2

Comment: Try calling only `this.Close();` without calling `Dispose()` and see if it help.

Comment: instead of setting a public static (global state is generally a bad idea) why not simply call close on the form? and then dispose it

Comment: actually i tried it first but form2 did not stop in that case too. if i just close and dispose form2 it does not stop even in the case with show.

Comment: where is the code for closing your Form2? when did you call it? I believe it's somewhere after `newForm.ShowDialog();` and that's why it never get called.

Comment: it is after newForm.ShowDialog();

Answer (score 0):

first of all you need to report progress to progressbar

```
 int iProgressPercentage = (int)(dProgressPercentage * 100);
 // update the progress bar
 progressBar1.ReportProgress(iProgressPercentage);
```

try doing that first then call this.close();

Answer (score 0):

As I said above in the comment, you need to check **Modal dialog** from here [Form.ShowDialog Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk.aspx), and I just quote the following form there:

> You can use this method to display a modal dialog box in your application. When this method is called, the code following it is not executed until after the dialog box is closed.

As why you can't see your `ProgressBar` on `Form2` with `Show();` you need to provide more information of how you handles it, as if I separate your program into two parts and use two `button click` to run them (Click button1 to show `Form2`; and click button2 to close it) I can see your expected result: the `progressbar`.

Without your further information, my best guess is something running prevents the Form2 to update its GUI.

Comment: ok when i use buttons just to open and close form2. it works well with show.
i have a button on my application(in form1).it first checks that textboxes are full then begins a process which it handles some file operations. 
when i write show(); in the else block, (where the file stuff is done) controls in form2 doesn't show

Comment: use a BackgroundWorker (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) to run your file operations and change status of From2, so those process/operations won't block your GUI